# bad classfile magic (cafebabe) or version 0033.0000

Tags: android

I am compiling my android application using terminal in linux 
I am getting the  Error "bad classfile magic (cafebabe) or version 0033.0000"

Please help

Thanks
Dharmendra

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, you are compiling with Java 7, or some other non-supported Java environment (e.g., GNU Classpath).

Comment: ya you are right dear i am using java 7 in my linux box, you tell me how to install jdk 1.6 in linux cent osbox  i am new in linux